# Kibana : how to do a visualisation with an mathematical expression?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

So I have 3 searches.

I'm interested in 3 lines of log (each line is a document, msg is a field)

```
S1 : msg = Sending to ELK
S2 : msg = ELK failure - rejected
S3 : msg = ELK failure due to us
```

Search 1 is a try, search 2 and 3 are failures, I need graph that display this :

`(CountS1-(CountS2+CountS3))/(CountS1/100)` on the Y axisand the date of the log on the X axis

I know how to use the date of the logs on the X axis but for the Y axis I can only do things such as count, average, sum, etc of 1 search only.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best solution is go to Scripted fields and create the field that you need.

You can do in this way for example:

(doc['CountS1'].value - (doc['CountS2'].value+doc['CountS3].value))/(doc['CountS1'].value/100)

With this you have a new field that you can use only reference the name that you given to the new field. For example you name this field as Example1, then in your visualize option will appear the new field.

Comment: Thanks, I was going toward that, however each of those line is in a different document, I don't see how to make a query that would store the 3 count in separate variable.
(post edited)

Comment: If you have all the data in the same index there isnt problem. You dont need to make that query if you can do a new filed to store that.

Comment: unfortunatly it won't be in the same index because logstash creates one index per day (like logstash-2015.10.28)

Comment: Then i would try to put all in the same index using tha date as a filed.